# How to Post Date time into MySQL using Java Spring Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, input

I have a from in jsp page using twitter bootstrap , now I want to post user selected date and time into database. What i have need to do ?

1. I have need to sort all post order by asc datetime.

Question:

1. What will be the input type ? text or date or datetime ?
2. What will be the model return type ? only Date ?
3. If I put datetime together in database, Can i pull them order by asc
   datetime ?
4. or Better to put date and time separate column ?

**My main task is to sort all data according to date and time .**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to store date-time data as long value instead of DateTime instance. Use new Date().getTime() function to get equivalent date-time in millis and store as long value in database.

You can easily covert this long value back to date-time (in java as well as in sql) easily.